# How can automatically identify or allow the user of my program to identify variables in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, hashtable

I have something of a subtle (I think) problem in Lisp, related to an earlier question I asked: [How do I name a variable after a string in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576239/how-do-i-name-a-variable-after-a-string-in-lisp?noredirect=1#comment129999560_73576239)

Here's how it goes:

1. I'm creating a language in which (among other things) the user inputs text strings, and my parser then creates uniquely-identified entity (and other stuff) based on their input.
2. A typical and simple input would be: my_name:my_contents -- where my_name is the name of the entity, and my_contents is a string.
3. So, I need to find a way to set up a lisp program that takes the user input, then creates the entities and identifies them based on the user's input.

So far I've considered two approaches:

- **A.** One variable per entity: when the user enters a string, Lisp takes my_name and creates a variable with that name, and puts my_contents inside. The drawback here is that I can't figure out how to set the name of the variable to some user-defined and mutable input such as my_name.
- **B.** A table, such as a hash-table: when the user enters a string, Lisp adds a row to a hash table with my_name as the key and my_contents as the entry. The drawback with this approach is that again I can't find a way to set the key as my_name at any given moment.

In summary, I'm looking for counsel on 1. how to name a variable after a user-defined string or 2. how to set a user-defined string as a key in a hash table or 3. whether there's a better approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this question and the other one you linked, I think what would help people understand your problem better would be to have a little bit of code explaining what you are currently doing (both an example code in your custom language and the Lisp code used to process it). Or if you have more experience with another language, you can also try showing what you would do in that language that needs to be translated in Lisp.

Answer (score 3):

If you're feeling confused, I suggest you breakdown your plan into smaller pieces. Or just use the repl to play with the ideas, that way you'll see many of your questions answered.

Start: create a hash table:

```
>> (make-hash-table)
;;... some hash table is created ...
```

N.B. below, you'll see that this type of hash table won't work with your string keys, but keep going:

wait, you need to refer to it, let's set it to a variable:

```
>> (setf my-hash *)
```

or similar:

```
>> (setf my-hash (make-hash-table))
```

add some values:

```
>> (setf (gethash "key1" my-hash) "value1")
>> (setf (gethash "key2" my-hash) "value2")
```

hmm, I'd like to see the values. There are a few options. Let's check CLHS for one of them: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_maphas.htm#maphash

Copy-paste the last line of the example:

```
>> (maphash #'(lambda (k v) (print (list k v))) my-hash)
("key1" "value1")
("key2" "value2")
NIL
```

Now I wonder if I can use gethash to reach entries:

```
>> (gethash "key1" my-hash)
NIL
```

I can't! That's because make-hash-table we used above defaults to using 'eql as the test predicate. We need to change that. Do everything again with a better suited hash table:

```
>> (setf my-hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal))
>> (setf (gethash "key1" my-hash) "value1")
>> (setf (gethash "key2" my-hash) "value2")
>> (maphash #'(lambda (k v) (print (list k v))) my-hash)
("key1" "value1")
("key2" "value2")
>> (gethash "key1" my-hash)
"value1"
```

that's better.

Forgive me for starting from basics before coming to your question. I felt like we sometimes forget the principles / basics. If you play with your repl like this, I guess you'll find that it'll be easier to find some of the answers you're looking for.

And now, to add to Numbra's answer, here is some pointers:

if you want to use hash tables:

```
>> (setf user-entered-string "VARIABLE1")
>> (setf user-entered-value "value1")
>> (setf (gethash user-entered-string) user-entered-value)
```

or, symbols:

```
>> (intern user-entered-string)
;; now it is a symbol object in current package:
>> (find-symbol user-entered-string)
>> (setf (symbol-value (find-symbol user-entered-string)) user-entered-value)
```

Comment: tip: `inspect` or `describe` work too to see the content of the hash-table.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to understand all of your problems, but:

#### Name a variable after a user-defined string:

The function that (more or less) does that is [intern](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_intern.htm) (or `read`, but that is way more general). You probably want to `intern` things in a "user package", so as not to conflict with the actual code.

#### Hash-tables

Here, I am not sure to really understand what it is that causes you troubles: if the user enters a string (that you can get with *e.g.* `read-line` or something more complex if you wish), bound in your code to, say, `user-string-name`, you can just do `(setf (gethash user-string-variable *user-defined-variables*) user-string-value)`, assuming you have created such a hash-table. Note that by default, hash-tables use `eql` to compare keys, which is not what you want for strings; you'll need to create the table with the argument `:test 'equal`.

#### Other option

Using symbol [property lists](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_symb_4.htm#symbol-plist).

---

There are probably even more solutions that I haven't thought of. Deciding which of those is the best probably depends on many things, and I'll let you decide, given your application, which one you prefer.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! So my question is this:

When I enter "(setf (gethash user-string-variable *user-defined-variables*) user-string-value)" I believe that it will create a row in the table with the key "user-string-variable", but I need it to be the actual string that the user entered -- how can I import this value in so as to use it as the key? Or please do let me know if I'm wrong!

Comment: It will not: (what I called) `user-string-variable` is simply a variable, and can have a value: look at @AlbusMPiroglu second-to-last code block to see what I mean. You need a way to "set" this variable in the first place, and as you are trying to prompt the user, I think `read-line` is fine.

Comment: Fabulous! It works! Thank you for the patience with a beginner!